# Unable to optimise MySQL query further: what am I missing?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I've got a query which seems to be impossible to optimise further (with regards to execution time). It's a plain simple query, indexes are in place, I've tried to configure InnoDB settings...but nothing really seems to help.

**Tables**

The query is a JOIN between the three tables trk, auf and paf.

- trk : temporary table holding id's representing tracks.
- auf : table representing audio files associated with the tracks.
- paf : table holding the id's of published audio files. Acts as a "filter".

```
// 'trk' table  
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE auf_713340 (  
  `id` char(36),   
  PRIMARY KEY (id)  
) ENGINE=MEMORY);  

// 'auf' table  
CREATE TABLE `file` (  
 `id` char(36) NOT NULL,  
 `track_id` char(36) NOT NULL,  
 `type` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `quality` int(1) DEFAULT '0',  
 `size` int(20) DEFAULT '0',  
 `duration` float DEFAULT '0',  
 `bitrate` int(6) DEFAULT '0',  
 `samplerate` int(5) DEFAULT '0',  
 `tagwritten` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
 `tagwriteattempts` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
 `audiodataread` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
 `audiodatareadattempts` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
 `converted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
 `convertattempts` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
 `waveformgenerated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
 `waveformgenerationattempts` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
 `flag` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
 `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
 `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',  
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
 KEY `FK_file_track` (`track_id`),  
 KEY `file_size` (`size`),  
 KEY `file_type` (`type`),  
 KEY `file_quality` (`quality`),  
 CONSTRAINT `file_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`track_id`) REFERENCES `track` (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

// 'paf' table  
CREATE TABLE `publishedfile` (  
  `file_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,  
  `data` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `file_updated` datetime NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The query usually takes between 1500 ms and 2500 ms to execute with somewhere between 50 and 100 ids in the trk table.The auf table holds about 1.1 million rows, and the paf table holds about 900.000 rows.

The MySQL server runs on a 4GB Rackspace Cloud Server instance.

**The Query**

```
SELECT auf.*
FROM auf_713340 trk
INNER JOIN file auf
  ON auf.track_id = trk.id
INNER JOIN publishedfile paf
  ON auf.id = paf.file_id
```

**The Query w/EXPLAIN**

```
id select_type table type   possible_keys         key           key_len ref                                 rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      trk   ALL    NULL                  NULL NULL     NULL                                        60  
1  SIMPLE      auf   ref    PRIMARY,FK_file_track FK_file_track 108     func                                1   Using where
1  SIMPLE      paf   eq_ref PRIMARY               PRIMARY       110     trackerdatabase_development.auf.id  1   Using where; Using index
```

**The InnoDB configuration**

```
[mysqld]

# The size of memory used to cache table data and indexes. The larger 
# this value is, the less I/O is needed to access data in tables. 
# Default value is 8MB. Recommendations point towards 70% - 80% of 
# available system memory.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2850M

# Recommendations point towards using O_DIRECT to avoid double buffering.
# innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

# Recommendations point towards using 256M.
# @see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/03/choosing-proper-innodb_log_file_size/
innodb_log_file_size=256M

# The size in bytes of the buffer that InnoDB uses to write to the log files
# on disk. Recommendations point towards using 4MB.
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M

# The size of the buffer used for MyISAM index blocks.
key_buffer_size=128M
```

Now, the question is; what can I do to get the query to perform better? After all, the tables in question are not that big and indexes are in place..?

Comment: Post the tables' definitions (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`).

Comment: Why does it list func as your reference for `auf`? You've got a straight comparison in the SQL you posted.

Comment: @ypercube :Added SHOW CREATE statementsm.

Comment: @scragar : Not sure...could it be because the 'trk' table is a temporary MEMORY table? I chose that path instead of doing a WHERE IN condition on 50 - 100 ids.

Comment: Since your charset is utf8, your key columns declared as CHAR(36) are actually taking up 108 bytes.  This is why the explain shows a key_len of 108.  The size of your "auf" table is probably 3 times bigger because of this.  Try changing all those id columns to BINARY(36) instead.

Comment: @bobwienholt : Does changing the id columns to BINARY(36) have any implications? Is BINARY(36) and CHAR(36) totally interchangable? I don't need sorting or anything else on the id column.

Comment: They are not totally interchangeable... but since your data (UUIDs) is always ASCII characters it should be fine.  If you really wanted to get fancy you could translate the text representation of the UUID into its 128-bit form and stuff it in a BINARY(16). This could help: https://gist.github.com/159151

Answer (score 0):

In auf table make id field as int(11) and make it auto increment. all int field length which are >11 , edit them into 11.

Thanks
Ripa Saha

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that's easier said than done. There are multiple applications depending on the id being a UUID (char) - meaning that this change would require entire applications to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for Your information. Primary key will always be unique. so INT is best type for primary key. If id CHAR(36) is dependent on your application then you may make this id as id_depend CHAR(36) and id INT(11). these 2 field may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, could be...but I have to admit that I am more interested in investigating performance improvements rather than redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT auf.* 
FROM file auf 
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM auf_713340 trk 
        WHERE auf.track_id = trk.id 
      )
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM publishedfile paf
        WHERE auf.id = paf.file_id
      ) ;
```

I would also test and compare efficiency with the temporary table defined with InnoDB engine or with the (Primary) index as a `BTREE` index. Memory tables have `HASH` indices by default, not Btree if I remember correctly.